# XML Rendering is different in IE and chrome?

Tags: asp.net, xml, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am showing XML on browser by using below method.

```
string fn="first_name";
        string ln = "last_name";
        string ec="0";
        string desc = "Success";
        string xml = "<response><variables><var name=\"" + fn + "\" expr=\"" + fName + "\" /><var name=\"" + ln + "\" expr=\"" + lName + "\" /></variables><error code=\"" + ec + "\" description =\"" + desc + "\" /></response>";

      //  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
      //  xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml); 

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Write(xml);
        Response.End();
```

and the result on Chrome is below

```
<response>
<variables>
<var name="first_name" expr="API"/>
<var name="last_name" expr="VCCAudit"/>
</variables>
<error code="0" description="Success"/>
</response>
```

and in IE it's in below format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<response>


-<variables>

<var expr="API" name="first_name"/>

<var expr="VCCAudit" name="last_name"/>

</variables>

<error description="Success" code="0"/>

</response>
```

The issue is Chrome show correct XML where as IE change the sequence of name and expr and the same thing happened in error tag where sequence of description and code changed.

Please Help in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The attributes doesn't have a specific order.

> "Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or
>   empty-element tag is not significant."

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

So, either way of showing the attributes is correct. The XML doesn't change meaning by reordering the attributes in a tag.

If you want the XML to be shown in any specific way, you need to display it yourself instead of relying on the built in support in the browser to show the XML.